# Mass import/edit data.

Tags: javascript, php

i'm not certain how hard this is going to be or even how to best describe it but i'll give it my best try.

I'm currently working with the Google Maps V3. In this version you can import polygons right in the map. Now i've got a whole list of coordinates which i need to insert in some other code. That sound extremely vague so let me elaborate.

The output the tool gives me is:

```
5.129585,52.337647,0.0 
5.129156,52.339744,0.0 
5.131559,52.341894,0.0
```

(this is only a small part).

Now i need to take these coordinates and insert them in this part:

```
  var  = [
      new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
      new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
      new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737)
  ];
```

(once again a small part).

There are a couple of facts to work with here. The couple's of coordinates are separated with a comma (,) coordinates can be both possitive as negative, the last item should not end with a comma, it needs to be imported in the order it is listed already.

Is there an excisting script that can do this, or an easy way to write one?

Comment: You just need `explode()`

Comment: Could you explain this a bit further? i found this explaining it a bit but its not yet clear how to use it. http://nl3.php.net/explode

Comment: your delimiter is `,` then you will recieve array with 3 elements, and I guess `0` and `1` element should be used in the javascript later

Answer (score 1):

Use php `explode()`

```
$cord = "5.129585,52.337647,0.0 ";
$exp = explode($cord);

$cord1 = $exp[0];   // 5.129585
$cord2 = $exp[1];   // 52.337647 


var  = [
  new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $cord1; ?>, <?php echo $cord2; ?>),
];
```

You can loop around co-ordinates (use foreach) since you have many of them.